# Are recursive calls made in a conditional statement?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, conditional-statements, binary-tree, depth

I'm trying to walkthrough the following recursive code to find the depth of a binary tree, but do not know if recursive calls in conditionals are called:

```
var maxDepth = function (root) {
  return maxDepthHandler(root, 1);
};

var maxDepthHandler = function (root, depth) {
  if (!root) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (!root.right && !root.left) {
    return depth;
  }
  if (root.right && root.left) {
    // are these recursive functions called when checking the condition?
    if (
      maxDepthHandler(root.right, depth + 1) >
      maxDepthHandler(root.left, depth + 1)
    ) {
      return maxDepthHandler(root.right, depth + 1);
    } else {
      // for my follow up question: is this the first recursive call?
      return maxDepthHandler(root.left, depth + 1);
    }
  } else if (root.right !== null) {
    return maxDepthHandler(root.right, depth + 1);
  } else {
    return maxDepthHandler(root.left, depth + 1);
  }
};
```

Given the following graph:

```
        13
       /  \
      8    37
     / \   / \
    6  11 24 42
```

If recursive calls aren't called in conditionals, does that mean running maxDepth(13) will result in `maxDepthHandler(root.left, depth + 1);` to be the first recursive call? The reason I think this is because at the first call, if recursive calls in conditionals are not called, the conditional cannot be calculated, therefore the else statement is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, they are all called. That implies that you should probably capture their values to avoid repeated effort:

```
let right = maxDepthHandler(root.right, depth + 1);
let left = maxDepthHandler(root.left, depth + 1);
if (right > left) {
  return right;
} else {
  return left;
}
```

or:

```
let right = maxDepthHandler(root.right, depth + 1);
let left = maxDepthHandler(root.left, depth + 1);
return right > left ? right : left;
```

or:

```
let right = maxDepthHandler(root.right, depth + 1);
let left = maxDepthHandler(root.left, depth + 1);
return Math.max(left, right);
```

or:

```
return Math.max(maxDepthHandler(root.left, depth + 1), maxDepthHandler(root.right, depth + 1));
```

As a side note, because you are handling the null `root` case by returning `0`, I think most of your other conditions on `root.right` and `root.left` being null will be handled automatically if your entire function becomes:

```
  if (!root) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Math.max(maxDepthHandler(root.left, depth + 1), maxDepthHandler(root.right, depth + 1));
```

However there are cases where function calls in conditionals are not called. For example:

```
if(foo(1) || foo(2)) {
...
}
if(foo(3) && foo(4)) {
...
}
```

In this example, if `foo(1)` returns `true`, the `||` operator will *short-circuit* and not bother calling `foo(2)`. If `foo(3)` returns `false`, the `&&` operator will short-circuit so `foo(4)` won't be called.

Comment: The short circuit you described is unwanted behavior correct? Meaning coding recursive functions in that format should be avoided? I don't capture each value because I need to recursively call maxDepthHandler until I hit the base case (not in my question since it did not relate to my question).

Comment: @boxcarcoder: I actually made a logic mistake in that first iteration, and corrected it. The general answer is: it depends on the purpose of your recursive function. For example, if the purpose was to find whether a given value exists in a structure, and the function simply returns `true` if it's found in one part of the structure, you might say `return find(value, root.left) || find(value, root.right)`. It would be fine for `find(..., root.right)` to not be called if the value was already found on the left, wouldn't it?

Comment: @boxcarcoder: In capturing the value, you would still recursively call it until you hit the base case. It just means that you wouldn't repeat the whole thing twice over. You'd only visit every node once instead of visiting them all twice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are called, as their value is needed to establish whether enter the if statement body.